# Al iniciar una pagina, que el Ajax se ejecute automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Lo que quiero es que al iniciar una pagina, se cargue el Ajax automáticamente, ya que ese sera el DIV que cargara otras pagina o funciones a futuro, pero de momento no se aparece o me marca nada. El JS no esta en la pagina central sino en otro archivo. Este es el código HTML y JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="cargaBio.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="loadDoc();">
            <!-- CENTRO -->
            <section id="centro">
                <div id="biografia_es"></div>
            </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
 function() loadDoc() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("biografia_es").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", ".\biografia_es.html", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

Cualquier ayuda se agradece.

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Redactando respuesta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberías consultar la consola de depuración de javascript con más frecuencia. Tu código genera los siguientes errores:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Function statements require a function name
>   Uncaught ReferenceError: loadDoc is not defined at onload

El primero es debido a que no estás definiendo correctamente la función:

```
function() loadDoc() {
```

Debería ser:

```
function loadDoc() {
```

Por eso al intentar llamar a la función `loadDoc`, que no ha sido definida, lanza el segundo error.

Prueba de funcionamiento:

```js
function loadDoc() {
    console.log('Cargando XHR');
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = () => {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("biografia_es").innerHTML = this.responseText;
        }
    };
    xhttp.open("GET", ".\biografia_es.html", true);
    xhttp.send();
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="cargaBio.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body onload="loadDoc();">
            <!-- CENTRO -->
            <section id="centro">
                <div id="biografia_es"></div>
            </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Estuve haciendo pruebas todo el día y no me funciono, aun así muchas gracias.

Comment: Al final lo hice así:



function loadDoc() {
 console.log('Cargando XHR');
 $("#biografia_es").load('biografia_es.html');
 return false;
}

Comment: ¿El qué no te funcionó? ¿La carga del archivo? Imagino que `".\biografia_es.html"` no es una ruta válida.

Comment: No me cargo el archivo, a pesar de los cambios, no entiendo el porque, la ruta si es la correcta, al final quedo mas sencillo, muchas gracias.

Comment: Me alegra que te funcione.